# jQuery Mobile Page Resizing is visible after load

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

**Update**
I've tracked the bug down to between the pageBeforeHide and pageBeforeShow events. Between these events, the class .ui-overlay-c is added and removed. Those CSS classes are shown here:

```
.ui-body-c,
.ui-overlay-c {
border: 1px solid       #aaa /*{c-body-border}*/;
color:                  #333 /*{c-body-color}*/;
text-shadow: 0 /*{c-body-shadow-x}*/ 1px /*{c-body-shadow-y}*/ 0 /*{c-body-shadow-radius}*/ #fff /*{c-body-shadow-color}*/;
background:             #f9f9f9 /*{c-body-background-color}*/;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from( #f9f9f9 /*{c-body-background-start}*/), to( #eee /*{c-body-background-end}*/)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( #f9f9f9 /*{c-body-background-start}*/, #eee /*{c-body-background-end}*/); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient( #f9f9f9 /*{c-body-background-start}*/, #eee /*{c-body-background-end}*/); /* FF3.6 */
background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient( #f9f9f9 /*{c-body-background-start}*/, #eee /*{c-body-background-end}*/); /* IE10 */
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient( #f9f9f9 /*{c-body-background-start}*/,     #eee /*{c-body-background-end}*/); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background-image:         linear-gradient( #f9f9f9 /*{c-body-background-start}*/,     #eee /*{c-body-background-end}*/);
}
.ui-overlay-c {
background-image: none;
border-width: 0;
}
```

**/Update**

I'm developing a touchscreen website and using the jQueryMobile library. The site is designed to run at 1366px x 768px but no smaller.

Most things are working across browsers but I'm running into a pesky bug that occurs during transitions. The pages are designed to be 99.55% width with a solid white 10px border on all edges. During transition, the page contracts by about 40px (only from the right side) and then when it loads the new page, that page is also contracted until expanding to fill the proper width.

I'm guessing that this is due to the nature of jQueryMobile transitions but I am having trouble stopping it from happening.

You can see this effect here [at this link](http://evanmrose.co/projects/dev/mediacombo/public/) by clicking once then on any of the navigation items. It should contract and expand after the first click.

The way jQM works, there is a mobile viewport wrapper which uses the following css:

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
position: absolute;
display:none;
border: 0;
```

During the transition between pages, the following styles are applied along the mobile viewport wrapper:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Within this viewport there are separate pages (.ui-page) each with the following css:

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
min-height: 100%;
position: absolute;
display: none; // overridden to display:block when the page is loaded
border: 0;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
```

Here are my custom styles that I apply at the page level alongside .ui-page:

```
color: black !important;
background-image: none !important;
background-color: #ddd2cc !important;
border: 10px solid white !important;
padding: 20px !important;
width: 95.55% !important;
```

I have limited knowledge of the jQueryMobile CSS innards but any guidance on how to stop the page from expanding/contracting would be helpful. My gut tells me that the issue is due to my css overriding jQM css and applying the padding after the page loads leading the user to be able to see this padding addition.

Comment: Any takers? Could really use the help.

Comment: So if you remove your custom CSS, things work normally? What you could do, is adding your custom CSS when page is shown after transition is over and remove your CSS before page is hidden and transition starts.

Comment: They work normally with the custom CSS as well @Omar the core issue is that even after page-load (everything is layed out and on page), the padding isn't applied. It is applied after everything is done at a point where the user is able to see it happening and it looks sloppy. I'm hoping to avoid this glitchy looking transition process by having the padding applied at an appropriate time before the user can see it and the page is loaded.

Comment: I've taken a look at your page. I guess you may need to add the classes on `pagebeforeshow` event and remove them on `pagehide`. Try `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` of your custom class.

Comment: @Tip_Top It isn't supposed to work on mobile, just an old school touch screen without multitouch

Comment: @Tip_top thanks for taking a look! I should add, old school touch screen with resolution 1366x768 running latest FFX or Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest fix ever:

```
$.mobile.maxTransitionWidth = 320;
```

jQM doesn't handle page transitions well at large viewport sizes. Turn them off and this bug goes away.

Comment: +1 very nice. It'll be useful to mention that this code should be placed in `head` and bound to `mobileinit` before loading jquery-mobile library.